# I can't solve this problem (node:15320) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Whenever i try to use !delcoms (amount) command this pops up in console and it just delets the command message.

I've tried to do everything i could.

```
if(message.content.startsWith(prefix + "delcom")){
    let args = message.content.split(" ").slice(1);
    let author = message.member;
    let role = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "Admin");
    if(author.roles.has(role.id)){

       }
      if(!args[0]){
        message.delete();
        message.author.send({embed: {
          color: 0x991501,
          description: "You need to write at least 1."
        }});
        return;
  }
if(args[0] > 100){
   message.delete();
   message.author.send({embed: {
    color: 0x991501,
    description: "Maximum number of delcoms is **100** at once"
  }});
   return;
}



message.delete();
 message.channel.bulkDelete(args[0]);
  message.author.send({embled:{ 
    color: 0x3ac45d, description: "Done, I deleted" + args[0] + " messages." 
}}) 
return; 

    }
```

I wan't to get rid of the problem so the command works. Thanks!

Comment: I imagine its a problem with calling `message.delete()`?

Comment: Yeah i think soo too

Comment: Hi again! I find this really weird if i do "  message.author.send({embled:{ 
    color: 0x3ac45d, description: "Done, I deleted" + args[0] + " messages." 
}}) " It dosnt work but if i do message.author.send ("Done, I deleted" + args[0] + " messages.")   It works :/

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is a typo..

> `message.author.send({embled:{ color: 0x3ac45d, description: "Done, I deleted" + args[0] + " messages." }})` It dosnt work but if i do `message.author.send ("Done, I deleted" + args[0] + " messages.")`

You wrote `embled` instead of **`embed`**

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you are having a race condition, try using something like [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) library and either use [async.waterfall](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html) or [async.series](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html)

Comment: Hi again! I find this really weird if i do "  message.author.send({embled:{ 
    color: 0x3ac45d, description: "Done, I deleted" + args[0] + " messages." 
}}) " It dosnt work but if i do message.author.send ("Done, I deleted" + args[0] + " messages.")   It works :/

Comment: Can i fix this without async? Muhand Jumah

Comment: @SijaiAps You can use callbacks. If you can create a quick example on http://repl.it/ and share it with me, I will be able to solve your issue. The reason I am asking you to create the sample because I am not familiar with discord.